# How do I disable There should be no space after '{'.eslintobject-curly-spacing in .eslintrc.js

Tags: eslint, visual-studio-code, prettier, eslintrc

I am using prettier and I initialized my project with firebase init with the eslint option. But when I save my files, the prettier extension adds spacing in the object curly braces like this:

```
export { basicHTTP } from './http';
```

which eslint gives me an error: [image: eslint error] is there anyway to disable this?

This is my .eslintrc.js file that comes with firebase init:

```
module.exports = {
  root: true,
  env: {
    es6: true,
    node: true,
  },
  extends: [
    'eslint:recommended',
    'plugin:import/errors',
    'plugin:import/warnings',
    'plugin:import/typescript',
    'google',
  ],
  parser: '@typescript-eslint/parser',
  parserOptions: {
    project: ['tsconfig.json', 'tsconfig.dev.json'],
    tsconfigRootDir: __dirname,
    sourceType: 'module',
  },
  ignorePatterns: [
    '/lib/**/*', // Ignore built files.
  ],
  plugins: ['@typescript-eslint', 'import'],
  rules: {
    quotes: ['error'],
  },
};
```

Comment: Have you had a look at the ESLint docs? They explain how to configure rules. https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#disabling-rules-with-inline-comments

Answer (score 14):

Modify your `rules` to look like this:

```js
rules: {
  'object-curly-spacing': ['error', 'always'],
  'quotes': ['error'],
},
```

After this change you probably have to fix all js files to use same syntax, but that's just a good practice.

See: https://eslint.org/docs/rules/quotes

Comment: This is about [object-curly-spacing](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/object-curly-spacing), quotes is not relevant, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

You can disable adding space in `vscode` when formatting code.

Open `settings.json` and add the following line

```
"typescript.format.insertSpaceAfterOpeningAndBeforeClosingNonemptyBraces": false,
"javascript.format.insertSpaceAfterOpeningAndBeforeClosingNonemptyBraces": false,
```

This will fix it on both javascript and typescript

Comment: Awesome! For those trying to find the file, follow these steps:
1. Press `Ctrl + Shift + P`, 2. Type 'user settings' in the search box, 3. Select `Preferences: Open User Settings (JSON)` option